# Android List View

Tags: android, image, listview, lazy-loading

So basically I have a function which is something like that :

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src)
```

, which return decrypted Bitmap.I need to be able to use that Bitmap into a Lazy loading ListView.
**Example :**
So I have a ListView.I'm downloading encrypted images and use that `getBitmapFromURL` function to return them as Bitmap,and after that I want to be able to reload the ListView with the new images which `getBitmapFromURL` returns to me.I want to find a way to save them in cache so when there is like 50 loaded jpg's in ListView I want to be able to delete the first loaded and keep only these which are visible while scrolling the ListView.And do exactly the same thing when I have another 50 loaded images.Any Suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: I have done a gridView with images that show a spinner and download image.. When download is complete, the image shows? Interested?

Comment: Actually yes,it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the well-known lazyList :

http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip

I have created the gridView with spinner I will upload it tomorrow and make it available (: Maybe create a tutorial ... I am off now I will keep you in mind

Comment: Actually I'm using the same LazyList,but I need to do a lot of changes to it.That's why I need to be able to load decrypted images,not from URL.Need to be able to set unique id for every row,because there will be some hidden images (instead of them there will be default image),and I need to find a way how to clear the cache automatically,not with a button.

Comment: I never used it ... But if there is a button to clear the cache, then all you have to do is copy the code inside into a function? each row is a view! so you can row.setTag("something unique").. finally, remark you can get the view using findViewByTag("its unique tag")

Comment: Ok,Thanks a lot for the help! And not only for this question,you really helped me a lot with other questions too!I'll update my progress after I do everything!

Comment: Actually everything goes right for now,except two things.First things is,I get an exception when I'm trying to decrypt only jpegs,there is no problem with png's.And the second is I'm not really sure how to get the loaded images from listview so when they are like 50 i can clear the cache and reload them.

Comment: @psychenaut let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2122/discussion-between-sherif-and-psychenaut)